# How do I limit the threads in a ATL DCOM service?

Tags: multithreading, atl, dcom

I have an ATL service which implements a free threaded COM object. Our testers are running more and more threads against the service but this eventually results in an ugly runtime crash when it starts running out of RAM.

How can I configure ATL (or COM) to limit the number of threads that are created inside the service?

I've been looking at the CComClassFactoryAutoThread. Looks like you enable this with the DECLARE_CLASSFACTORY_AUTO_THREAD macro but I don't know if I can use this with a service. Also how do I limit the thread pool size if I use this?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Are those threads created by your code, such as worker threads, or COM is creating too many threads to serve external requests? You should be easily able to see by taking a snapshot of your process in death agony state.

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: No unfortunately. The nature of the application means that you have to have a very large enterprise deployment to cause this so our testing group decided it was an acceptable risk.